# Where is the symfony 2 path() method defined

Tags: symfony

I want to see how it works. In particular if it is doing a explode on "_" or if it is searching the routing for a equivalent key based on the parameter you are passing in.

I searched the docs, the 'nets, and my codebase, except there isn't much info on where it lives. The symfony docs use it when they are building links.

```
    {# src/Acme/TaskBundle/Resources/views/Default/new.html.twig #}
    <form action="{{ path('task_new') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
        {{ form_widget(form) }}

        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
```

---

Looks like it uses the key in the routing file. So the following code:

```
    {{ path('_welcome') }}
```

would be looking for routing with a key of '_welcome' in your routing.

yaml

```
    _welcome:
        pattern:   /
        defaults:  { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Main:homepage }
```

php

```
    use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;
    use Symfony\Component\Routing\Route;

    $collection = new RouteCollection();
    $collection->add('_welcome', new Route('/', array(
        '_controller' => 'AcmeDemoBundle:Main:homepage',
    )));

    return $collection;
```

Comment: Why should Symfony 2 should explode `_ `? It simply loot at route name, throwing an exception if route does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is defined in

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Extension/RoutingExtension.php

which makes use of

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Generator/UrlGenerator.php

Anyway, I can confirm that it is not doing any explode on '_'

Comment: So yea looks like its based off the key in the routing file. Thanks man!